# Постраничное разделение текста в UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, textview, ebook, uitextview

Пишу читалку ePub под iOS: книги парсятся с помощью KFEpubController и в результате получаю массив глав книги в формате html. Для отображения страниц с перелистыванием (page curl как в iBooks) планирую использовать PageViewController но столкнулся с проблемой: как разбить длинный текст главы\книги на необходимые фрагменты для отображения на отдельных страницах. Другими словами - как вычислить длину текста, которую может вместить UITextView определенного размера, чтобы потом разбить длинный текст на страницы?

Спасибо!

Comment: Удалось решить проблему с разбивкой текста? Если да, то подскажите, пожалуйста, как?

Answer (score 1):

Вот например, код, вычисляющий высоту текста для отображении в `UITableViewCell`:

```
if let text = textSections?[indexPath.section][consts.key] {
    return text.boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width - consts.widthOffset, height: CGFloat.max), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: consts.font], context: nil).size.height + consts.heightOffset
}
```

вот Objective-C и вычисление size

```
CGSize baseSize = /* базовый размер, в который нужно вписать текст */
CGSize textSize = [text boundingRectWithSize: baseSize options:  NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue" size: 13]}].size;
```

Comment: Я в свифте не очень, но это же вроде вычисление размера который необходим тексту с определенным шрифтом? Мне нужно наоборот - вычислить длину текста для определенного размера.

Comment: Это очень легко перевести в ObjC. Я не совсем понимаю, что это значит "вычислить длину текста для определенного размера". Этот метод вычисляет размер, то есть и ширину, и высоту.

Comment: Ну суть в том, что у меня есть длинный текст, который нужно разбить на части так, чтобы каждая часть умещалась в UITextView целиком без скроллинга.